# C# Android Xamarin - if-else statement not working

Tags: c#, android, if-statement, xamarin

I have a problem with an if-else statement I'm using in my C# code. Currently, I'm building an app with Xamarin in MS Visual Studio. I want the event "uitrekenen" to check whether the three edit objects actually have a value. If not, I want the object "totaalTekst" to show a message like: "Please fill everything in.", or something. When I debug the code on my phone, I get an error. The error must have something to do with the event "uitrekenen", because without this event (as you see it here) I don't get any errors. The code might be a bit confusing, since I used Dutch names for the objects. I hope anyone here knows what the problem could be! I appreciate your help and if anything isn't clear about my question; please ask!

Here is the code:
My question especially concerns the last part, containing the event "uitrekenen".

```
using Android.OS;       // vanwege Bundle
using Android.App;      // vanwege Activity
using Android.Widget;   // vanwege TextView
using Android.Graphics; // vanwege Color
using System;

[ActivityAttribute(Label = "Leeftijd", MainLauncher = true)]
public class LeeftijdApp : Activity
{
EditText dagEdit;
EditText maandEdit;
EditText jaarEdit;
TextView totaalTekst;

protected override void OnCreate(Bundle b)
{
    base.OnCreate(b);

    TextView dagVerzoek;
    dagVerzoek = new TextView(this);
    dagVerzoek.Text = "DD:";
    TextView maandVerzoek;
    maandVerzoek = new TextView(this);
    maandVerzoek.Text = "MM:";
    TextView jaarVerzoek;
    jaarVerzoek = new TextView(this);
    jaarVerzoek.Text = "JJJJ:";

    dagEdit = new EditText(this);
    maandEdit = new EditText(this);
    jaarEdit = new EditText(this);

    Button knop;
    knop = new Button(this);
    knop.Text = "Klik hier!";

    totaalTekst = new TextView(this);
    totaalTekst.Text = "Hallo daar!";

    knop.Click += uitrekenen;

    LinearLayout stapel;
    stapel = new LinearLayout(this);
    stapel.Orientation = Orientation.Vertical;
    stapel.AddView(dagVerzoek);
    stapel.AddView(dagEdit);
    stapel.AddView(maandVerzoek);
    stapel.AddView(maandEdit);
    stapel.AddView(jaarVerzoek);
    stapel.AddView(jaarEdit);
    stapel.AddView(knop);
    stapel.AddView(totaalTekst);

    this.SetContentView(stapel);
}
protected void uitrekenen(object o, EventArgs ea)
{
    if (dagEdit != null && maandEdit != null && jaarEdit != null)
    {
        int DD = int.Parse(dagEdit.Text);
        int MM = int.Parse(maandEdit.Text);
        int JJJJ = int.Parse(jaarEdit.Text);
    }
    else
    {
        totaalTekst.Text = "Vul alle waarden in!";
    }
}
}
```

Comment: If app crashing show error logs also and add `null` check for `dagEdit.Text` values before parsing String to int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first, It is a joke to ask for help but not even translating code in english. But okay

Your code will crash because of this line:

```
int.Parse(tfEdit.Text);
```

int.Parse is throwing a exception when the input is not parseable, if you dont want to catch the exception you could use int.TryParse

Because the method uitrekenen gets executed on the main thread and you are not catching any exception in that method the main thread will have a unhandled exception which will crash the app.

So the solution would be to use one of this two solutions:

```
try{ 
    int DD = int.Parse(dagEdit.Text);
    int MM = int.Parse(maandEdit.Text);
    int JJJJ = int.Parse(jaarEdit.Text);
}catch(Exception ex){
    //do whatever you want with your exception
}
```

Or

```
int DD,MM,JJJJ;
int.TryParse(dagEdit.Text,DD);
int.TryParse(maandEdit.Text,MM);
int.TryParse(jaarEdit.Text,JJJJ);
```

Also you shouldn't check the textfield objects for null because you know they got initalized, but you should check the .Text property for null

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Next time, I'll make sure my code is entirely in English.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (dagEdit != null && maandEdit != null && jaarEdit != null) {...}
```

You check objects, but you need check *values*.

like that:

```
if (dagEdit.Text != "" ...) {...}
```